# Angular Animate Unknown provider: $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue

Tags: angularjs

When I'm running my app I'm getting an error,

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$forceReflowProvider <- $$forceReflow <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue

I've read that it might be because the animate and angular version are out of sync but that's not the case.

my `bower.json`:

```
"angular": "1.4.8",
"angular-animate": "1.4.8",
```

I've also removed my `bower_components` folder and did a `bower install` but the error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: did you add the `angular-animate.js` file to your sources (in `index.html`)?

Comment: Stupid question: Are the libs for angular-animate included in head? (or whereever you include the libs in the index HTML)

Comment: @yarons yes, otherwise I wouldn't even get the error.

Comment: @FlorianTopf All the needed files are added, and I've injected the `ngAnimate` service in my application. Otherwise I wouldn't have the error to begin with.

Comment: Hey did you solved the problem ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @KimberlyBF Like I said in the answer below, for me the solution was to change the sprockets gem (I was using Ruby on Rails) to 3.2.0 and that fixed it. I'm not sure what the deeper problem was though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening, but it looks like the problem has to do with the sprockets gem. If I change the sprockets gem to `sprockets (3.2.0)` in the gemlock file I can open the app with no problems.